# Selenium Java finding input field after an error message

Tags: java, selenium

i am sending an incorrect email address in the Confirm email and clicking Register in a site and my code loosing focus on that input field and not find the input file again. What should i do my code is

```
    WebElement Email = Driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress"));
    Email.sendKeys("sanjeevmenon@gmail.com");
    WebElement CEmail = Driver.findElement(By.id("confirmemail"));
    CEmail.sendKeys("sanjeevmeno@gmail.com");
    WebElement RegButton = Driver.findElement(By.id("register"));   
    RegButton.click();
```

I get an error message saying my emails dont match After this i am trying to send the right value to the input field but my program is not identifying our loosing the focus. Please help.

Comment: How to implement Wait Until, please advise

Comment: You can use this to implement wait.until:   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("emailAddress")));

Comment: First you are sending wrong input values, after that you can check when the input contains error message or empty message(means there no error text). If the there is an error you can resend the details to same input fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the register button the page elements are most likely being refreshed in some sort of way. What I like to do is make a `Wait.until()` call on the presence of the error message. That will only appear after the refresh is complete. Then, you'll want to make sure you put `CEmail = Driver.findElement(By.id("confirmemail"));` before calling `CEmail.clear();` and `CEmail.sendKeys();`. The previous instance of `CEmail` was destroyed, so you need to re-find it.

You might already have a `WebDriverWait` defined, if you do, just use that instead.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("INSERT ERROR MESSSAGE ID HERE")));
```

Comment: Hi Mate i deliberately sending incorrect values to the fields so that i get a error message and i dont know how to get the focus back on the input field again so that i send the right value

Comment: @SanjeevMenon My mistake, I should have read your question more closely, I will update the answer. Give me a second.

Comment: How to implement Wait.until() please advise

Comment: @SanjeevMenon `ExpectedConditions` is located in the `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui` package.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try refreshing the page? That could resolve the issue!!

driver.navigate().refresh();